# Why are conservation laws quasilinear?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My notes say the conservation law is an example of quasilinear pde  $$\partial_t U + \partial_x F(U)=0$$

because it can be written as
$$\partial_t U + F'(U)\partial_x U=0$$

**The definition of quasilinear is that it is linear "in the highest-order derivatives",  does it mean that If I take the terms containing the highest order derivatives  they must be linear ?**

For example, the Burgers equation:
$$\partial_t U + U\partial_x U=0$$

Being of order 1, both terms are of highest order: $\partial_t U$ in clearly linear, but I don't think the other one is, since there is a multiplication, so taking a linear combination $\alpha U + \beta V$

$  (\alpha U + \beta V)\partial_x  (\alpha U + \beta V)= \alpha^2 U \partial_x U + \beta^2 V \partial_x V+ \alpha \beta U \partial_x V + \alpha \beta V \partial_x U$

wich is clearly non linear. I think I would expect to get $\alpha U \partial_x U + \beta V \partial_x V$ to regard it as linear

**Can someone clear this up?**

Comment: @Ian So I must ignore the coefficient $U$ in $U \partial_x U$?, But following that, if i have something like  $U (\partial_x U) ^2$ I could as well ignore the power and the derivative $(\partial_x U) $  itself will always be linear

Comment: Yes...but you can't ignore the power in this sense because that's built into the dependence on the derivative directly. Basically pretend you can freeze everything about $U$ other than the highest order derivatives and then ask whether the equation is linear in the highest order derivatives with this freezing being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means the direct dependence on the highest order derivatives (regarded as variables in their own right, separate from the functions they were derived from) is linear. Which is true for the Burgers equation, since $U(\alpha \partial_x U_1 + \beta \partial_x U_2)=\alpha U \partial_x U_1 + \beta U \partial_x U_2$, even though one obviously cannot literally replace $\partial_x U$ by $\alpha \partial_x U_1 + \beta \partial_x U_2$ without also updating $U$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that any pair $(\rho,J)$ obeying $\partial_t \rho=-\nabla \cdot J$ expresses a conservation law: via Stokes law one can check that the "conserved charge" $\rho$ is indeed conserved locally ($\rho$ can be "drained/replenished" at infinity or in coordinate singularities and therefore $\int dx\,\rho(x,t)$ need not be constant). The pair $(\rho,J)$ is often called a conserved current. In geometric language, such a current is a $(n-1)-$form on a $n-$dimensional smooth manifold. The continuity equation in that setting simplifies to $dJ=0$, where $d$ is the exterior derivative. Anyway, the continuity equation is -at face value- linear in the partial derivatives. Since this continuity equation is underdetermined (or non-autonomous) in and of itself, it often supplemented with a consitutive relation for the current $J=J(\rho)$. If the dependence of $J$ on $\rho$ is of the form $J(x)\equiv f(\rho(x),x)$, then the resulting continuity equation remains first-order in the partial derivatives, but we could as well have $J(x)\equiv f(\nabla \rho(x),\rho(x),x)$ where the same is no longer the case.

Comment: Why is the continuity equation non-autonomous? Even in the case $J(x)=f(\rho(x),x)$? I am trying to expand it to check the coefficients do not depend on $\rho$.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO The continuity equation itself is underdetermined. The autonomous resolution is to give a constitutive relation; the non-autonomous resolution is to specify $J$ from outside.

Comment: Sorry, so the use of the word autonomous here is not the same as in ODE, where $\dot x=f(x,t)$ is autonomous if f(x,t)=f(x) ?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO It's the same; the point is that you could determine the behavior of the continuity equation by just specifying $J(x,t)$ at all times from outside.